# question about "attributes" attribute of a class

Tags: python, django

This is probably a simple question but I'm wondering why it seems attribute names and values are reversed in the following example:

```
>>> class SelectOne(DjangoChoices):
...     cola = ChoiceItem("c", "Coca Cola")
...     beer = ChoiceItem("b", "Heineken")
...
>>> SelectOne
<class 'SelectOne'>
>>> SelectOne.attributes
OrderedDict([('c', 'cola'), ('b', 'beer')])
>>> for k, v in SelectOne.attributes.items():
...     print (k, v)
...
c cola
b beer
```

Common understanding should be that "cola" is the key and "c" is the value. where can I find the documentation of "attributes" attribute of a class?

Comment: This is a confusing terminology overlap - one of the *attributes* of a `SelectOne` instance is *named `attributes`*. You can find the documentation of that attribute [in the documentation](https://django-choices.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the library that provides the class.

Comment: Thanks. understand now. this is specific to DjangoChoices class.